# Regular Expression lazy modifier matches too much

Tags: regex

The following regular expression is jumping **[url]** tags...

***Regular Expression*** (generic regular expression)

```
(?:\[url.*?\])(.*?youtu.*?)(?:\[\/url\])
```

***String:***

```
[url]blahyoutubeblah[/url] heyya [url]blahblah[/url]    [url]www.youtube.com/blah[/url]
```

Help!!

[image]

Comment: also you should say what flavour of regex you are using..... I presume js

Comment: it fails because you say match any character until youtu, then look for /url

Comment: @KeithNicholas    yes... js or PHP....  thanks but I thought the lazy modifier ***.*?*** would fix that so it would get minimum length string.  ??

Comment: try `(?:\[url.*?\])(.*?.*?)(?:\[\/url\])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your captured group requires `youtu` inside, so the substring

```
[url]blahblah[/url]    [url]www.youtube.com/blah[/url]
```

matches, because it starts with `[url]`, includes `youtu`, and ends with `[/url]`.

Simply using a negated character set, excluding `[`, probably isn't enough, because that wouldn't allow for nested tags to match, such as an input of

```
[url]foobar youtube[b]BOLD TEXT[/b][/url]
```

You might require negative lookahead for `[/url]` right before each repeated character:

```
(?:(?!\[\/url\]).)*
```

Also, make sure that whatever comes after the `[url` does not contain `]`s before coming to the true `]`, with:

```
\[url[^]]*\]
```

In full:

```
\[url[^]]*\]((?:(?!\[\/url\]).)*youtu(?:(?!\[\/url\]).)*)\[\/url\]
```

There's no need to make the quantifiers lazy anymore, because of the negative lookahead.

Demo:

https://regex101.com/r/hSAJEp/1

Comment: you're awesome.  why require a negative lookahead for [/url]? before repeated characters?

Comment: Because otherwise, the substring at the top of the answer (`[url]blahblah[/url]    [url]www.youtube.com/blah[/url]`) will match. You don't want any `[/url]`s to be in between the first `[url]` and the final `[/url]`.

Answer (score 1):

You are matching `.*` which means it will match `url`, up until `youtu`, then find `/url`

A simple workaround could be something like which means it won't match a opening `[` bracket before finding `youtu`

```
(?:\[url.*?\])([^\[]*?youtu.*?)(?:\[\/url\])
```

Answer (score 1):

It's lazy, but it still will match if it can - it won't be moving left border if match is possible. There are other things to do that. One of them is just to prevent unwanted match by regex itself - just use

```
(?:\[url[^\]]*?\])([^\[]*?youtu.*?)(?:\[\/url\])
```

Comment: you're awesome.  this site is awesome.  thanks!

Comment: @zdanman, if it solves your problem, accept an answer by clicking a check on the left of it.

Comment: THANKS Qwertiy I had to end up using the one by CertainPerformance because it allows other tags ( such as **[B][/B]**, **[U][/U]** ) to be included in the group result - and specifically targets the **[URL][/URL]** tag to be excluded.  I so very appreciate your help though!  Truly!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that there is `youtu` you had in your regex but there was `blahblah` between `url` to be matched, making it generic 
so

```
(?:\[url.*?\])(.*?)(?:\[\/url\])
```

Comment: I think he wants to find url tags with `youtu` inside, but you'll find any.

Comment: he just said jumping `url`